# Whats the most native solution for highlight UITableViewCell on touch but keep selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

What I want to achieve you can see in the native clock app.
When you select a ringtone the cell gets the checkmark accessory and highlights on touch, but it unhighlights directly afterwards with a fade animation.

So my question is, is there a way to use temporarily native cell highlighting via  the `selectionStyle` of my `UITableViewCell` instance AND keep the selection afterwards to show the accessory view.

I know that I can just write `tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)` in the `didSelectRowAt` delegate method. But this removes the ability to bind the checkmark to the selection state.

I also know that I can animate the background of the cell on my own, but this is bad since iOS could change the default highlight color and I want my app to feel as native as possible with as less custom UI code as possible.

Is there a native way that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Theres two options I can think of.

---

Easiest but loses the unhighlight animation.

Set `allowsSelection` to `true` on your tableview and override `setSelected` on your cell to do this.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    accessoryType = (selected ? .checkmark : .none)
}
```

It will highlight the cell when the user presses it, then show a checkmark.

---

More complicated but keeps the animation.

Don't use the `allowsSelection` property on the tableview and track the selected row yourself.

In `cellForRowAt:` you need to set the cell to show/hide the checkmark.

In `didSelectRowAt:` you need to remove the checkmark from the old selected row, update your value tracking the selected row, and add the checkmark to the new selected row.

Comment: Both of your options don't answer my question. But thanks for option one. I forgot about the opportunity to override the `setSelected` method. This saves a few lines. 
But I think I have to handle the highlighting on my own...

Comment: How does it not answer your question?

Comment: Your first option doesn't include the highlight animation. Your second one suggests doing things on my own, what are already natively implemented. 
I'm looking for a native way to do both, highlighting/unhighlighting on touch down/up but keeping the selection after the touch up.

Comment: I figured giving you possible solutions would be better than just saying "No, there is no native way to do that."